# How specify a parameter in a FORMAT control-string on Common Lisp as variable?

Tags: format, common-lisp

What I can done:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~10:<foobar~>")
"    foobar"
```

But I want pass `10` as parameter like:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~d:<foobar~>" 10) ;; but throws error
"    foobar"
```

Exists any way to do that? Because I don't wants do that:

```
CL-USER> (format nil (format nil "~~~d:<foobar~~>" 10))
"    foobar"
```

In Python or C is possible passing variable parameters to control-string using `*`, like this:

```
print("%*s" % (10, "foobar"))
```

I wants just the same in Common Lisp format. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, is just use `~v` instead `~d`. This was described here:

> In place of a prefix parameter to a directive, V (or v) can be used. In this case, format takes an argument from args as a parameter to the directive. The argument should be an integer or character. If the arg used by a V parameter is nil, the effect is as if the parameter had been omitted.

See: [22.3 Formatted Output - Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm)

```
CL-USER > (format nil "~v:<foobar~>" 10)
"    foobar"
```